# Disable browser Back button of asp.net ajax page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

```
Design page containing Update panel

</head>
<body onkeydown="KeysShortcut(event);" onload="pageLoad();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelMain" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>


                <ajaxControlToolkit:DropShadowExtender ID="DropShadowExtender2" runat="server" Opacity="0.6" Rounded="false" Radius="5" TrackPosition="true" TargetControlID="pnlMain" Width="8"></ajaxControlToolkit:DropShadowExtender>
                <table align="center" width="100%">
                <tr>
                <td align="center">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlTests" runat="server">
```

**Script I have included**

```
///
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function DisableBackButton()
        { window.history.forward() }
        DisableBackButton();
        window.onload = DisableBackButton;
        window.onpageshow = function (evt) {
            if (evt.persisted) Disabl`enter code here`eBackButton()
        }
        window.onunload = function ()
        { void (0) }
        window.history.forward(1);
 </script>
```

above script is working fine with .aspx pages but not working with aspx pages containing update panel of ajax script manager

Comment: In a word (or two) you can't.

Comment: See http://forums.asp.net/t/989339.aspx/1 for pros and cons and maybe a solution.

Comment: It explains me It is not right to disable back button. There are solutions on google but i cant find the right one

Comment: <script>history.go(1)</script>

Comment: This is not working when Ajax update panel on the .aspx page

Comment: It is working fine with Firefox but not working with Chrome..